# How to use "import" in jsx file on play framework

Tags: reactjs, playframework

I have a problem in using to ReactRouter.

The problem is that when I try to import "Router" in jsx or js file, like so:

```
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
```

It gives me the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

I guess because "ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)" is not supported in a browser. How to solve this problem and use RectRouter in PlayFramework?

#### My env :

1. Intellij 15
2. Playframework 2.5
3. sbt

#### In my build.sbt:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.0")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// ReactJS
addSbtPlugin("com.github.ddispaltro" % "sbt-reactjs" % "0.5.2")
addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.1")
```

Comment: You can use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your ES6 into vanilla JavaScript, which is runnable by any browser.